# Parameter order: size, count or the other way round

Tags: readability, code-formatting

I hope this is the right forum for this ... Well, in C, the standard library uses usually `(void* buffer, int size)` when referring to some data buffer. I wonder if there is a rationale for this order instead of `(int size, void* buffer)`. I couldn't think of any good reason, and it seems to be an arbitrary choice, but I'm curious to here if there is some deeper meaning behind this order.

Comment: alphabetical order, obviously. **b** uffer comes before **s** ize. Or something else.

Comment: Totally arbitrary. Just be consistent.

Comment: Well, something like `process (3, elements)` is closer to plain English, which makes it more "natural".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C you can't do `object->method(value)`, so it's idiomatic to put the "object"—the thing whose state you're changing—as the first parameter, and prefix the function name with the "class."  The C standard library makes a lot more sense when you think about it that way.  For example, `strcpy(dest, src)` reads as `dest->cpy(src)`, where `dest` is a `str` object.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you prefer the data parameters first and then the const values. 
There is also a preference for the result first  eg strcpy(dest,src)  memcpy(dest,src)

In c++ it's useful because you can have default parameters at the end.

Comment: Yeah, which I/most people I know always wind up doing wrong, because you say "I want to copy a to b" (usually) but you write it the other way round.